# Code sniffer custom PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.MultipleArguments rule

Tags: phpcodesniffer

Hi I need change rule `PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature.MultipleArguments` to using tabs.
Now I have custom config:

```xml
    <arg name="tab-width" value="4"/>

    <rule ref="PSR2">
        <exclude name="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowTabIndent"/>
        <exclude name="Generic.Files.LineLength.TooLong"/>
        <exclude name="Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace.ContentBefore"/>
    </rule>

    <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent"/>

    <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
        <properties>
            <property name="indent" value="4"/>
            <property name="tabIndent" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </rule>
```

When I use `phpcbf`, fix is ok:
from

```php
$this->afpJobService->createFileThumb(
    $this->a, $this->b, $this->c, $this->d, $e
);
```

to:

```php
$this->afpJobService->createFileThumb(
    $this->a, 
    $this->b, 
    $this->c, 
    $this->d, 
    $e
);
```

But use SPACES, no TABS. How can I change it?
command is run with parameter `sniffs=PSR2.Methods.FunctionCallSignature`